# Is there a way to delete a label with the same button that also adds a label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.9

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text="enter Something below")
label.pack()
textbox = Entry(root)
textbox.pack()
label2 = Label(root, text = textbox.get())
def save():
    
    if label2.winfo_exists == 1:
        label2.pack_forget()
        label2.pack()

    else:
        label2.pack_forget()
        label2.pack()

button = Button(root, text="press for repetition", command=save)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Nothing gets deleted when I press the button for a second time, so what I am trying to do is to delete what has already been packed with the same button. So if I input Hello, then How are you?

it comes out something like this:

```
Enter Something below
(this is the textbox)
Hello
How are you?
```

I want the `Hello` to have been deleted and only the `How are you?` to have shown.

Comment: First `if label2.winfo_exists == 1:` should be `if label2.winfo_exists() == 1`.  But what the point of checking it here as it always True because you have created the label before that line?  Second `label2` is local variable.  Therefore every time the button is clicked, you cannot destroy the last label as the reference to the label is destroyed.  Why don't you just create the label once outside the function and update its text inside the function?

Comment: @CoolCloud It is not your post, so why do you modify the posted code?  You can fix typos or gramma, but not the code.

Comment: @acw1668 it still doesn't work when I try it like you said.

Comment: Update your posted code or add the update code.

Comment: @acw1668  Ok I updated it
When I enter something then I click the button, no word comes up. Its blank.
I changed it to ```label2.pack_forget()``` because trying to pack it after using ```label2.destroy()``` it raises an error because it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: As said in my first comment, `if label2.winfo_exists == 1` should be `if label2.winfo_exists() == 1`.  But it is not necessary as it will always be True.  Also there is no different between the if block and else block.  And your update code does not update the label.

Comment: So what should I do?
Forgetting to add the brackets is ```label2.winfo_exists() == 1``` was just shown here by mistake. I added the brackets in the actual code @acw1668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to destroy the label and recreate the label.  Just create the label once, then update its text inside `save()` function:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text="enter Something below")
label.pack()
textbox = Entry(root)
textbox.pack()
label2 = Label(root) # create the hidden label 
def save():
    # update the label text
    label2.config(text=textbox.get()) 
    # show the label. remove 'before=button' to show it below the button
    label2.pack(before=button) 
button = Button(root, text="press for repetition", command=save)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks!
I removed the ```before = Button``` and it works exactly how you said.